# Mac only shows either WiFi 5GHz or 2.4GHz but not both

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

I thought updating to MacOS Mojave would solve this issue but it still occurs every time I login my Mac:

I want to connect to 2.4G WiFi but in the WiFi list it only shows the 5G one, then I disable WiFi and enable it again, then repeat it twice or 3 times, and it will finally shows the 2.4G one meanwhile 5G disappears.

The router has both 2.4G and 5G WiFi and in the past when I used other routers my Mac could show both in the list but not with this router so does this have something to do with the router rather than my Macbook?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if both bands are transmitting the same SSID on your router (the name of the network as it appears in the list). If they are the same, change one of them slightly so the SSID names are different.  Reboot the router Then you should be able to see both in the list of wifi networks and connect to either.

Comment: What if the names are already different? E.g. 2.4G name is MyWiFi and 5G name is MyWiFi-5G but they still do not both appear in the list the same time.